# Random likelihood function during maximizing process

Tags: maximum-likelihood, measure-theory

Mostly common definition of Maximum Likelihood Estimator in certain parametric problem $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n),\mathcal{P}=\{\mathbb{P}_\theta\mid\theta\in\Theta\})$is what follows:
$$
\hat\theta_{MLE}(\mathbf{x})\equiv\underset{\theta\in\Theta}{\operatorname{argmax}}L_n(\theta\mid\mathbf{x}),\quad\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}
$$
It means that for all n-dimensional data points $\mathbf{x}$ we have unique solution, which maximize Likelihood function. Then, during the process of maximizing Likelihood is considered as non-random function of $\theta$, with data given. I am interested under what assumption we can treat the Likelihood as random in process of deriving estimator- i look for more formal, measure-theoretic approach to this problem. I think that the likelihood should be measurable function, differentiable in $\theta\quad a.s\quad\mathcal{P}$. Am I right? What else?

Comment: There is no need for the likelihood to be either measurable nor differentiable in $\theta.$ Insisting on that would introduce unnecessary restrictions and rule out the applicability of this theory in some significant situations.

Comment: The random function $L_n(\theta\mid\mathbf{x})$ 
should be measurable in $\theta$ (at the very least, to talk about existence of argmax you need more structure) $\mathcal{P}$-a.s. The argmax $\hat\theta_{MLE}$ should be a measurable function of data $\mathbf{x}$, as any estimator should be. 
There is no requirement that $L_n(\theta\mid\mathbf{x})$ be jointly measurable in $\theta$ and $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\left(\mathcal X, \mathcal A, \left(\mathbb P_\vartheta\right)_{\vartheta \in \Theta}\right)$ be a statistical model consisting of

- a set $\mathcal X$ (the sample space),
- a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ on $\mathcal X$,
- a family of probability measures $\left(\mathbb P_\vartheta\right)_{\vartheta \in \Theta}$ on $\mathcal A$ with
- index set (the parameter space) $\Theta$ of cardinality bigger than one.

If, for all $\vartheta \in \Theta$, $\mathbb P_\vartheta$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal A$, then the likelihood function $\mathcal L$ is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#In_general) as the [Radon–Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Formal_description) of $\mathbb P_\vartheta$ w.r.t. $\mu$:
$$
\mathcal L(\vartheta, x) \mathrel{:=} \frac{\mathrm d \mathbb P_\vartheta}{\mathrm d \mu}(x), \; \forall \, \vartheta \in \Theta, x \in \mathcal X,
$$
and often viewed as a function in $\vartheta$.

Thus, the (random) likelihood process is the random process of the corresponding Radon–Nikodym derivative.